# Am I using setTimeout() correctly in timing when these javascript functions fire?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, settimeout, timing

I am using the Google Maps API v3 to create an interactive map with markers on the map and info windows that open up when you click the markers. The process is you create a marker, create an info window, and bind the two with a click (the event will also close any other open info windows).

This works just fine.

I wanted the markers to drop in succession, so I added a delay which grows based on count for each marker.

After I did this I noticed that the the click events weren't able to find the markers that were created.  I assume this is because the markers were not created yet as they were still in delay.

My solution was to add a delay to the binding function equal to the last marker's delay + a little extra time.

My question is if this is the best way of controlling this situation?

Pseudo-code overview:

```
function mapInit(){

    google create map code;
    //Begin First PHP loop, pulls all information in
    setTimeout(function(){  //PHP loop iteration 1
        create marker1;
        create window1;
    }, 1 * 150);

    setTimeout(function(){  //PHP loop iteration 2
        create marker2;
        create window2;
    }, 2 * 150);

    setTimeout(function(){  //PHP loop iteration 3
        create marker3;
        create window3;
    }, 3 * 150);
                            //end first PHP loop

    function createListeners(){

        //begin second PHP loop over markers

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {  //iteration 1

            //internal loop over windows and if for each window
            open window1;  //if is true, open instead of close
            close window2;
            close window3;
        }
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {  //iteration 2

            //internal loop over windows and if for each window    
            open window2;
            close window1;
            close window3;
        }
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function() {  //iteration 3

            //internal loop over windows and if for each window
            open window3;
            close window1;
            close window2;
        }
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        createListeners();
    }, 3 * 150 + 100);}

}

on window.load call mapInit();
```

More details:

The javascript is created dynamically in PHP. I am pulling the marker and window information from an external source, and as I loop through that the markers and window information is written, and at the end of that loop the listeners are all created.

When the script is actually ran on page load, it timeouts between each marker/window creation.  As soon as a marker is made it is loaded onto the map.  If I were to put the marker/window addListener in the same timeout, it will not see the marker/windows that are to be created after its creation, and thus the addListener will not be complete.

Comment: Why not just put the `addListener()` code *inside* the timer callbacks?

Comment: Trying to synchronize `n` timers to execute corresponding events together is almost never the answer.

Comment: @Pointy This code is created dynamically.  In order for all the addListener()s to be created, all the markers and info windows must be known as the listener must open 1 and close the rest.

Comment: @Alex W I was thinking that would be the case, and that's why I'm here, any suggestions?  I'm relatively new to the language and all of its options.

Comment: Well then you'll need to post more information to describe the situation more thoroughly.

Comment: Added information Pointy, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't matter that these are generated dynamically in PHP, because in the end the JavaScript won't ever notice. Since you have created `marker-x` and `window-x` already by the end of your `setTimeout` it should be feasible to add an event listener to them:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    create marker1;
    create window1;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
        open window1;
        close window2;
        close window3;
    };
}, 1 * 150);
```

If you don't know how many items there will be, you can keep track of it in PHP and then pass that info along to JavaScript (e.g. `echo "var numOfItems = " . $numItems . ";";`)

Comment: Won't it be an issue that within 1 function you are creating only the first marker and window, yet creating a listener involving windows which have not been created as they are on a longer timeout?

Comment: @MR.H. Yes. I would create all of the windows first. If you need to create them in a loop then you should keep track of how many there are in PHP and then pass that information to the JavaScript. When you create the window it shouldn't render anything, so that won't affect the dropping effect of the markers.